# PowerShell command is not working in a script

Tags: powershell

I created a simple PowerShell script to log into a remote computer and then execute a command but the command does not execute. The command is "cd C:". Here is the script:

#Script to do an RDP to a remote server

Enable-PSRemoting -Force

$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "xxxxxxxxx" -AsPlainText -Force
$username = "NE\a_chermes2"
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $password)

Enter-PSSession -ComputerName NESCH11 -Credential $cred

Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {cd C:}

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 1):

You enter into a remote session, you have no need to use `Invoke-Command` here, and this do not execute because of the double hop restriction. Despite you can add more code to allow it, this is not useful here.

Moreover, `Enter-PSSession -ComputerName NESCH11 -Credential $cred` will be running separately than the rest of the script. This mean that `cd C:\` will be executed on your local machine - just like all other commands after it.

Use `Invoke-Command` instead:

```
Enable-PSRemoting -Force
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "xxxxxxxxx" -AsPlainText -Force $username = "NE\a_chermes2" $Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $password)
Invoke-Command -ComputerName NESCH11 -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {cd C:}
```

Of course, this will not do anything noticeable since all is done remotely and you only change the directory location. Try `Get-ChildItem C:` instead of `cd C:`. This syntax allow you to collect data remotely :

```
$dirList = Invoke-Command -ComputerName NESCH11 -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {gci C:}
```

Comment: my bad, I was tired to answer this :), sorry, see my edit. And please, DO NOT show your password here ;)